# Is there a hereditary $\sigma$-space $X$ such that it is not $Q$-space?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, selection-principles

A topological space $X$ is called a  **$\sigma$-space** if every $F_{\sigma}$-subset of $X$ is $G_{\delta}$.

A topological space $X$ is called a **$Q$-space** if any subset of $X$ is $F_{\sigma}$.

**Definition.** A topological space $X$ is called a  **hereditary $\sigma$-space** if every subset of $X$ is $\sigma$-space.

**Question.** Is there a hereditary $\sigma$-space $X$ such that it is not $Q$-space ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every $S_1(B_\Gamma,B_\Gamma)$ space is a $\sigma$-space, and the property $S_1(B_\Gamma,B_\Gamma)$ is hereditary for subsets (B. Tsaban and M. Scheepers, [The combinatorics of Borel covers](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(01)00078-5), Topology and its Applications 121 (2002), 357-382.)

For example, a Sierpiński set satisfies $S_1(B_\Gamma,B_\Gamma)$.

On the other hand, it is very difficult to be a Q-set. For example, Q-sets have Lebesgue measure zero. In particular, they cannot be Sierpiński.